# How can I test if a current view controller is the first responder/top most view controller once a application becomes active

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

What I would specifically like to do is test in a view controller X's view will appear method

```
if ('view controller X' is the first responder) {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(TestSelector2:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
}
```

'view controller x' in the above example code is nothing but 'self', I used view controller x for clarity

because currently every view controller I have subscribing to the UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification is getting called and they are each calling theire respective methods. I would only like one view controller to be notified that the application became active at a time, the view controller I would like to be notified should always be the one visible to the user (the first responder). Can someone help, I am new to IOS dev

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a navigation controller you can access it using [`navigationController.visibleViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/visibleViewController)

Comment: so if(self.navigationcontroller.visibleViewController) ?

Comment: Yes... I'm assuming your navigationController is set up from the app delegate? Do it there.

Comment: this is how one of my current view controllers subscribes to the appdidbecomeactive notification, in viewdidLoad I have this line of code: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(TestSelector:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];

Comment: I would like it so that my view controller only subscribes if it is currently visible, but I am struggling as to exactly where to put the code, in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear

Comment: If your viewcontroller is observing that notification, and is active in memory, it WILL respond, along with all other view controllers observing that notification. One way is to remove the notification observers and selectively invoke the method on the desired viewcontroller from appdelegate (I recommend this). Another way is to check and see in the `TestSelector:` method, if(self.navigationController.visibleViewController == self) and only then run the code (do not recommend --- bad design).

Comment: wait why is it bad design to check and see in the test selector itself? Thats what I was about to do

Comment: You're welcome. Welcome to the community, and please be sure to mark my answer as correct if it helped you out. Thanks!

Comment: I tried sending notifications selectively to the view controllers from the app delegate before, but it was not working. I have gotten it to work by having each view subscribe in viewDidLoad only

Comment: Abhay, it's bad design because every time you make a new view controller, you have to implement that code. A way to circumvent this would be to have a root viewcontroller class that does this that you subclass everything else from. It's not a clean implementation, that's all. But you're fairly new to iOS so go with what's comfortable for now, but keep code management in mind.